# Align div tab with another div tag

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following script which works almost perfectly thanks to [Chris Moutray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81053/chris-moutray).

**jQuery:**

```
$('.navigation3').click(function(event) {
    var $nav3 = $(this),
        $dd = $nav3.next('.dropdown');

    $nav3.toggleClass('active');

    var offset = 20,
        offsettop = $nav3.offset().top + $nav3.height() + offset,
        offsetleft = $nav3.offset().left;

    $dd.css({
        top: offsettop,
        left: offsetleft
    });

    $nav3.hasClass('active') ? $dd.show() : $dd.hide();
});​
```

**The problem:**

The only issue is that the `.dropdown`'s are appearing so the top-left corner of the `.dropdown`'s are next to the bottom-left corners of `.navigation3`'s.

So basically, the lip of the `.dropdown`'s should be on the left side.  At the moment, the lip is on the right side.

**The question:**

How do I get the `.dropdown`s' top-right corner to align with the bottom-right corner of the `.navigation3`s'?

**jsfiddle example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/MTESY/19/

Comment: Please provide some context. Setup an example in jsfiddle.net, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
var leftoffset = $dd.width() - $nav3.width();

var offset = 20,
    offsettop = $nav3.offset().top + $nav3.height() + offset,
    offsetleft = $nav3.offset().left-leftoffset ;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MTESY/20/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider a more semantic way to write your menu with less CSS and jQuery - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MTESY/25/)

***HTML***

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>click me 1
        <ul>
            <li>icon Default 1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>click me 2
        <ul>
            <li>icon Default 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>click me 3
        <ul>
            <li>icon Default 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

***jQuery***

```
$("#menu > li").on("click", function() {
    var $ul = $(this).find("ul");
    if ( $ul.is(":hidden") ) { $ul.show(); } else { $ul.hide(); }
});
```

​

​
***CSS***

```css
#menu {
    float: right;
    background:#555;
}

#menu li {
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
}

#menu li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #c00;
}
```